# How to make input in textboxes appear in excel export?

Tags: html, excel, data-conversion

i am trying for a html table data to excel exporting for my project but How to make input in textboxes appear in excel export? for example.

//javascript

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

//html

```
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column One </th>
        <th>Column Two</th>
        <th>Column Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>row2 Col1</td>
        <td>row2 Col2</td>
        <td>row2 Col3</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row3 Col1</td>
        <td>row3 Col2</td>
        <td>row3 Col3</td>  
   </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/xhYcD/light/

Comment: Your statement is correct. Please clarify what you are asking. _How to make input in textboxes appear in excel export?_ for example.

Comment: is there any solutions????

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, when I face the same issue.

EDIT: Previous post has only link, here is the sample code that may help you.

```
function write_to_excel() 
{
    var ele;
    var str = "";

    var myTable = document.getElementById('tableId');
    var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
    var colCount = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("th").length; 

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
        ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

       for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) 
       {   
          for(var j=0; j<colCount; j++) 
         {           
            ele= myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
            if (ele.firstChild.type == undefined) {
                str = ele.innerHTML;
            }
            else if (ele.firstChild.type == "text") {
                str = ele.firstChild.value;
            }
            ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your link is a step in the right direction, it does not solve the problem for textboxes. Even if it did, *"link only"* answers are not valid answers. Please edit your answer to include the solution, or it will be flagged for closure.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mark : Sorry for just giving only link, I just thought of giving multiple solutions in a post. Thank you for giving awareness, if the link become invalid.